# Building an android apk from HTML/CSS/JavaScript App using Cordova on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: html, cordova, apk

I have successfully built apk out of HTML/CSS/JavaScript App using Cordova. And I can successfully install the run the app on my tablet (android version 9) . However, some pages in my app fails to load. Some pages which required keyboard input doesn't work etc. When I copy over same content and host it over apache, they work fine. I wonder what I am missing.

Here is what I do:

1. I use https://github.com/slaszu/docker-compose-cordova-android.git to run cordova environment.
2. Inside of cordova container, I add "cordova platform add android" to add platform. ( Gets version8.1.0)
3. I copy contents of html folder over into the www folder
4. I have config.xml inside of my www folder which looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.abc" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>ABC 1-3</name>
    <description>
       epaath app  
    </description>
    <author email="abc@example.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        nepal team  
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="www/img/logo.png" />    
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

5. I have index.html file with following lines added in suitable place

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-3.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ole.index.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ole.search.js" defer></script>

    <script>
```

6. I use following commands to generate apk
   #cordova build clean
   #cordova build android

Tried building apk using cordova.
It was successful.
Got some minor issues while loading the pages.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with simple HTML that you can share with us? When you run in apache, are you viewing on the same Android device? Did you check multiple devices — was it the same on all of them?

Comment: yes. The files hosted through apache work on the same android machine. It is just the app that has the issue.